# Ignore one specific row from MySQL output

Tags: php, mysql

I have written an application that contains a users MySQL table. The following code finds users from the table that have a coolness rating within 20% of the current user's coolness rating.

```
$query = "SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS WHERE RATING BETWEEN ".$coolnessRating." * 0.8 AND ".$coolnessRating." * 1.2";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo $row['USERNAME'];
}
```

My problem is this: if I have a user  and their coolness rating is 20 for example, they themselves are returned in the result set as obviously their own rating is within 20% of their rating if that makes sense.

Is there a way to ignore this specific row but print out the rest of the result set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If I have a user" means you have their username or id, right? Add the condition to your where clause with [AND](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp).

Comment: Oh, and clearly you're vulnerable to SQL injection/ Little Bobby Tables, but I assume this is a learning exercise.

Comment: Yeah it's for my final year university project. I'm going to go through later anyway and escape the PHP variables

Comment: @Tiffany If you need to escape SQL input, then you're already doing it wrong. Look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

Are you just wanting to add not equal to your WHERE criteria:

```
SELECT USERNAME 
FROM USERS 
WHERE RATING <> ".$coolnessRating." 
    AND RATING BETWEEN ".$coolnessRating." * 0.8 AND ".$coolnessRating." * 1.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgoing the usual "Use PDO! Your Code is vulnerable!" spiel, you would include another AND "not this user" condition

```
$query = "SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS WHERE RATING BETWEEN ".$coolnessRating." * 0.8 AND ".$coolnessRating." * 1.2 AND USERNAME != ".$user."";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo $row['USERNAME'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter it out with another part to your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT USERNAME
FROM USERS
WHERE RATING BETWEEN $coolnessRating * 0.8 AND $coolnessRating * 1.2
AND USER_ID != $current_user_id
```

(Obviously the last line depends on what the column name is and how you're storing the current user ID)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the information from the current user such as their id or username.

Then you can do

```
$query = "SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS WHERE RATING BETWEEN ".$coolnessRating." * 0.8 AND ".$coolnessRating." * 1.2 AND id != " . $id;
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS WHERE RATING BETWEEN ".$coolnessRating." * 0.8 AND ".$coolnessRating." * 1.2 AND id != " . $username;
```

where $username and $id are the current user's id and username

Answer (score 0):

Why not having your condition < 20% I can't tell though because you didn't mention the expected passed values